# Ember is not updating my page unless I go to home and the back to the route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been trying to lean ember with a small example without ember data. The applications has de data on a javascript object and I transform it to an Ember Object but it seems that I am doing something wrong, as when I add or delete any element of the array the list shown on the screen does not update until I go back to home and then select again the same route.

I have created a jsbin with the small code. I have been looking other examples of ember but I do not get what I am doing wrong.

Please, take a look at http://jsbin.com/uRucAKUH/2/edit?html,js,output

Any suggestion is more than welcome ;)
I also paste the code here

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0/ember.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        <ul>
          <li>Cars: {{cars.length}}</li>
          <li>Bikes: {{bikes.length}}</li>
          <li>trucks: {{trucks.length}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>{{#link-to 'cars'}} Show cars {{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'bikes'}} Show bikes {{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="cars">
       <button {{action "del"}}>Delete</button>
       <button {{action "add"}}>Add</button>
          Cars
          <ul>
              {{#each item in model}}
              <li>Car name <label> {{#link-to 'car' item.id}}{{item.name}} {{/link-to}} </label>
      {{/each}}
          </ul>
          {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bikes">
          <button {{action "del"}}>Delete</button>
          <button {{action "add"}}>Add</button>
          <ul>
              {{#each item in model}}
              <li>Bike name <label> {{#link-to 'bike' item.id}}{{item.name}} {{/link-to}} </label>
              {{/each}}
          </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="car">
          <p>
              Car details
          </p>
          <ul>
              <li><label>name:  {{name}}</label></li>
              <li><label>Owner {{input type=checkbox checked=owner}}</label></li>
              <li><label>Id is {{id}}</label></li>
          </ul>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource("cars", function(){
            this.resource("car",{path: '/car/:id'});
        });
        this.resource("bikes", function(){
            this.resource("bike",{path: '/bike/:id'});
        });
});
var legacyData = {
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "car 1",
            "id": 1,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "car 2",
            "id": 2,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "car 3",
            "id": 3,
            "owner": true
        }
    ],
    "bikes": [
        {
            "name": "bikes 1",
            "id": 1,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "bikes 2",
            "id": 2,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "bikes 3",
            "id": 3,
            "owner": true
        }
    ],
    "trucks": [
        {
            "name": "truck 1",
            "id": 1,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "truck 2",
            "id": 2,
            "owner": true
        },
        {
            "name": "truck 3",
            "id": 3,
            "owner": true
        }
    ]
};
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.data;
    }
});

App.CarsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.data.get("cars");
    }
});
App.CarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    find: function(param){
        console.log("Asking for specific CAcar "+param.id);
        var temp = App.data.cars.findBy('id',param.id);
        return temp;    }
});
App.CarsCarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    find: function(param){
        console.log("Asking for specific CarsCar "+param.id);
        var temp = App.data.cars.findBy('id',param.id);
        return temp;

    }
});

App.BikesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.data.get("bikes");
    }
});

App.Data = Ember.Object.extend();
App.data = App.Data.create(legacyData);

App.CarsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions:{
        add: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("cars");
            temp.push({
                id: "10001001",
                name: "Added Elem"
            });
            App.data.set("cars",temp);
        },
        del: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("cars");
            temp.pop();
            App.data.set("cars",temp);
        }
    }
});

App.BikesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions:{
        add: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("bikes");
            temp.push({
                id: "10001001",
                name: "Added Elem"
            });
            App.data.set("bikes",temp);
        },
        del: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("bikes");
            temp.pop();
            App.data.set("bikes",temp);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method `addObject` and `popObject` of `Ember.Arrayproxy` to manipulate your arrays. (Plz note that i removed the set on App.data. It is not needed.) Here is an example for the CarsController:

```
App.CarsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions:{
        add: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("cars");
            temp.addObject({
                id: "10001001",
                name: "Added Elem"
            });
        },
        del: function(){
            var temp = App.data.get("cars");
            temp.popObject();
        }
    }
});
```

But even better would be to do it like in  the following. **Instead of accessing your array as a global variable, you should directly manipulate the array of the ArrayController.** This way the ArrayController is not coupled to where your content/model array is stored. You will likely abandon the global array very soon (or replace it with an ajax call or whatever) and this approach will still work then.

```
App.CarsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        actions:{
            add: function(){
                this.addObject({
                    id: "10001001",
                    name: "Added Elem"
                });
            },
            del: function(){
                this.popObject();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have to see how I could delete a single element when viewing the selected element from the list. This must be easy, but I do not have a clear idead about how to do it :(

Comment: Here some buzzwords for you: Use the `needs : [cars]` property of a controller to get access to a CarsController inside a CarController. Call the appropriate method and afterwards do a transition to your Cars Route. Details on the `needs`API: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_needs

Answer (score 0):

In the "del" methods, use popObject() rather than pop()